# Is there a way to accept custom object in the routes using playframework?

Tags: java, playframework, routes, sbt

I want accept a request body of the post request as User object in routes. I am using Play version 2.7.1

```
POST    /user/create    controllers.UserController.createUser(user : User)
```

My User object looks like this.

```
public class User{
   @NotNull
   String userId;

   @NotNull
   String userName;

   @NotNull
   @NotEmpty
   String userCity;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

My createUser method looks like this.

```
public Result createUser(User user){
        //do smething with user
}
```

When I compile, I get an error saying that `not found: type User`

The reason I wanted to accept this way is to validate the request object `user` using hibernate validations, which look like the below code

```
public Result createUser(@Valid User user) {
        //do smething with user
}
```

I have already looked into PathBindable and QueryStringBindable. Both of them are not useful to me , as user is not a path paramter or query parameter, but a post request

In the end, I want the framework to convert the request body into the User object and take care of validations, instead of writing code for  converting the Json object into User object using Jackson library and validate the User object using Javax Validator.

Currently I am using these below functions for Deserialization and Validation

```
public static <T> T deserialize(String json, TypeReference type) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T bean = mapper.readValue(json, type);
        validateBean(bean);
        return bean;
}

public static <T> void validateBean(T bean) throws IOException {
        for (ConstraintViolation violation : beanValidator.validate(bean)) {
            throw new IOException(violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + " " + violation.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are mixing query parameters and request body.

All parameters that you pass from routes files are query parameters and `controllers.UserController.createUser(user : User)` will try to get your User from query params but it can happen only with help of PathBindable. As you don't pass user from query your routes will look like:

```
POST    /user/create    controllers.UserController.createUser()
```

And in your controller you will read POST body and parse json that you received:

```
public Result createUser(Http.Request request) {
  JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
  // Convert to java object and do what you want
  return ok("It works");
}
```

Comment: So, are you saying that we can only bind path parameter or query parameters? Can't we bind the request body to the route?

Comment: You can bind everything to same query, but in routes file you can only show query part. That’s how play framework designed